# Cutting off first instead of last letters in UILabel and UITextField?

Tags: ios, string, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

This may be a simple question, but after searching for 20 minutes without being successful I thought I may ask it here.

When a text gets too long in UILabel and UITextField, the displayed string looks something like this:

> very long text in lab...

This suits most cases, however now I want the displayed string to look something like this:

> ...ry long text in label

An iOS example would be the phone app, where the first letters get cut off, instead of the last ones. This is exactly what I want to achieve. I'm using Swift at the moment, but I would highly appreciate a solution in Objective-C, too.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C:
`label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead;`

Swift:
`label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingHead`